# Preposition in "driving to the mountains"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-choice

> 1. He is driving to the mountains.

Does it mean that he is driving to reach to the mountains, he hasn't reached but he is driving to reach in the mountains?

And, which sentence is correct?

> 1. He is driving to reach to the mountains.
> 2. He is driving to reach the mountains

Answer (score 1):

> He is driving to the mountains.

This means he is driving toward fhe mountains and probably will get there. It does not specify whether he will stop at the base of the mountains. If you wanted to make it clear that he will carry on when he reaches the base of the mountains, you would say

> He is driving into the mountains.

This would probably mean "entering the mountainous area", not driving inside the mountains for example into a tunnel.

For your sentences, it is not necessary to use **reach**. You might, however, say something like this, meaning that he won't stop until he arrives:

> He is driving until he reaches the mountains.

It is not necessary to use **to** with the verb [reach](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reach) when you mean **arrive**.

Comment: does it mean that he is going to the mountains? And please answer my second question of my main question. Thank you.

Comment: Yes.  1 is grammatically incorrect, 2 is grammatically correct but not idiomatic.